Can't capture/override notifications from remote website in Electron app
I'm trying to create a simple Electron wrapper for a website that adds some desktop functionality to it: tray integration, notification handling, etc. However, I think I'm not understanding how IPC is supposed to work here.
The remote website generates notifications from time to time, and I need to catch those notifications to present a different, richer notification to the user. Unfortunately I'm unable to catch the notifications at all (they continue to trigger Windows notifications directly).
In my main.js, I'm doing this:
const { app, BrowserWindow, shell, Notification } = require('electron/main')
const path = require('node:path')
const ipc = require('electron').ipcMain;

const createWindow = () => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1024,
        height: 768,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
        },
    })

    mainWindow.loadURL("https://myremotewebsite")

    mainWindow.on('close', function (event) {
        if (!app.isQuiting) {
            event.preventDefault();
            mainWindow.hide();
            showNotification("My App Name", "Window closed")
        }
        return false;
    });
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow()

    app.on('activate', () => {
        if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
    })
})

function showNotification(title, body) {
    notification = new Notification({ title: title, body: body })
    
    notification.on('click', (event, arg) => {
        mainWindow.moveTop()
        mainWindow.focus()
    })
    notification.show()
    console.log("Sent close notification")
}

ipc.on('notification-show', function (event, arg) {
    console.log("Detected incoming notification")
    showNotification("Custom notification", "Caught you!")
});

Then, on my preload.js:
const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

var Notification = function(title,ops) {
    ipc.send("notification-show", {title: title, options: ops});
};
Notification.requestPermission = () => {};
Notification.permission = "granted";
window.Notification = Notification;

I have included a dumb trigger to generate a custom notification whenever the window is closed, just to confirm that I can correctly generate custom notifications.
So it's only the previous step that's failing: override the notifications coming from the remote website.
Based on previous SO answers, my understanding is that the code in preload.js should override the native notifications API, instead sending a notification-show message through the IPC, that I should be able to catch from main.js using ipc.on('notification-show', ...).
But that's not happening, and notifications from the remote website continue to be shown directly by the OS without my function intercepting anything. The code inside ipc.on('notification-show'...) just never seems to run.
What am I doing wrong here? Am I misunderstanding how the preload script works?
